# Is there any legal things I need to discuss with Canonical before publishing an Ubuntu-based distribution?

Tags: canonical, legal, trademark

I would like to know if there is some legal stuff I should fix with Canonical in order to make my distro publicly available as it is based in Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have the right to modify and redistribute Ubuntu under the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html).

As long as you don't infringe any trademarks like 'ubuntu' or 'buntu' for example calling it 'Jorge ubuntu' without permission, or claim to be officially endorsed or assiosiated with Ubuntu / Canonical then you should be fine.

[You should read this link for clarification and contact Canonical if you are unsure.](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy)
  They were very helpful when we asked permission to use their trademarks.